# Angular 8 NgRx - Error: Detected unserializable action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I need to have a global Error object in my app state. So I created an http interceptor to dispatch `setError` action:

```
export interface IlgError {
  message: string;
  responseError: HttpErrorResponse;
}

export const setError = createAction("[Global] Error Occurred", props<{ errorObj: IlgError }>());
```

but when I dispatch I get the error:

> Error: Detected unserializable action at "errorObj.responseError"

My settings for app module:

```
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ routerState: RouterState.Minimal }),
```

What exactly does it mean "unserializable"? Can I disable this for some of my actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error is coming from this line:

```
 props<{ errorObj: IlgError }>
```

I recommend that you put a plain object into your store into something like this:

```
export const login = createAction(
    '[Login Page] Login',
    props<{username: string; password: string;}>(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing an object with properties in `props` object would solve the issue, but it would become cumbersome when you have quite a few number of properties in the object to be passed.

The better way would be to defined the action as:

```
export const login = createAction(
 '[Login Page] Login',
  props<IlgError>(),
)
```

and use below to dispatch the action

```
  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Login Page] Login'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError((error: IlgError) => of(failureAction(error)),)
      ))
    )
  );
```

Comment: With interface its working, but not with class :( Any update on this @Kaashan, thanks in advance