# Ngrx 8 mistakenly claims my state is unserializable

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I recently updated a project at work to Angular 8, and consequently, Ngrx 8.  I noticed that once I did so, I started getting this warning message in my builds/test runs:

`WARN: '@ngrx/store: runtime checks are currently opt-in but will be the default in the next major version with the possibility to opt-out, see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8 for more information.'`

So I read the doc, said to myself, "Okay, fine no big deal. My state should be serializable."  However, on at runtime, I would get this error:

`ERROR Error: Detected unserializable state at "rootState...`

I had no idea why it thought this.  I could get it to work with the following config for my StoreModule.forRoot declaration:

```
runtimeChecks: {
          strictStateImmutability: false,
          strictActionImmutability: false,
          strictStateSerializability: true,
          strictActionSerializability: false,
        }
```

but I still didn't understand why it thought there was a problem with my state.  After investigating, it seems that any object in state instantiated as an es6 class is considered unserializable.  See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-serialization-poc for a proof of concept (and look at the console window).

It seems the reason why is because of this line, in the `isPlainObject` method (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/meta-reducers/utils.ts, line #38):

```
  const targetPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(target);
  return targetPrototype === Object.prototype || targetPrototype === null;
```

My question is, am I correct that this code will only pass on an object literal? (i.e. `const x = {}`).  I don't understand why an es6 class would be considered unserializable, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you can view the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153800/angular-8-ngrx-error-detected-unserializable-action/57156589#57156589)

Comment: @tony-ngo that just tells me that an object literal will work, which I already know.  The question is why are classes not considered serializable?

Answer (score 0):

A class is not serializable, it must be a POJO.
If you would deserialize it, it won't be a class object anymore.

Also, for more info see https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/437